# orientdb etl Continue after Exception

Tags: orientdb

I have my ETL script as  :

```
 { 
      "config" : { "log": "debug"},
      "source": { "file": { "path": "C:/Users/60886/person.csv" } },
      "extractor": { "row": {} },
      "transformers": [
        { "csv": {} },
        { "vertex": { "class": "Person" } }
      ],
      "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
           "dbURL": "remote:localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts",
           "dbType": "graph", 
           "wal": false,
           "tx": false,
           "indexes": [
             {"class":"Person", "fields":["ID:LONG"], "type":"UNIQUE" }
           ],
           "batchCommit":1000
        }
      }
    }
```

After executing this script i get OETLProcessHaltedException , due to some exception , and the process halts. As a result it halts the complete ETL process. I want to continue loading other vertices after the Exception occurs, so that due to single erroneous record , my entire process doesn't stop. How can i achieve this ? Thanks!

Comment: Which exception do you get?

Comment: I get exception as :  Cannot index record Person{ID:1,Friend:101,Enemy:104,Name:A}: found duplicated key '1' in index 'Person.ID' previously assigned to the record #15:0 RID=#15:0
ETL process halted: com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessHaltedException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.ORecordDuplicatedException: Cannot index record Person{ID:1,Friend:101,Enemy:104,Name:A}: found duplicated key '1' in index 'Person.ID' previously assigned to the record #15:0 RID=#15:0.

Comment: I know that it can be fixed with flag called "skipDuplicates": true" , but in that case i would not be knowing which all records are duplicate, until i check the records in graph.

Comment: So you just want to log the exception but continue the etl?

Comment: Yes. I want to log which all records failed to persist and continue with the non duplicate entries.